# Button Styles theme not working in Android Dark theme mode (Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight)

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I have applied an android `background attribute` in the `android button`. While in the `day/light` mode the attribute gets applied perfectly with no issues but when switching to the `night/dark mode`, the attribute is not applied and a button with `grey background` appears instead of the `theme applied`.

This is my android button code:

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/logoutbtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/logout_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background_accent_rounded"
                />
```

And this is my drawable code for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient android:startColor="#2EBAC6"
    android:endColor="#4DDCE8"
    android:angle="180" />
<corners android:radius="300dp" />
```

The output I got was:

1. for day mode

[image: 1. for Day mode]

2. for night mode

[image: 2. for night mode]

Any help or suggestions without changing the java code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use a reference as `@color/mycolor1` instead of `#4DDCE8` and then use the `values-night\colors.xml` and `values\colors.xml` resources.